# How to get program's current directory in Node.js program using pkg?

Tags: node.js

I use node.js and i install pkg module to convert my js file to exe.

```
pkg app.js
```

But after convert, __dirname variable is invalid. It does not point it's(my program's) full directory path.
It just get very strange path like 'C:/snapshot/NodeProj'.
That path is not exist and before packaging __dirname variable was fine but it just get invalid path after packaging.

How should i gonna do to get real directory path?

Comment: well... process.cwd() is fine but it can not use during code in vs code. ( It only returns valid path after pakaging. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `process.pkg` **property** as conditional variable.

it'll be undefined during development mode, that time you can use `__dirname`

and during packaged application it'll have value so you can use `process.cwd()`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants a ready solution, here you go:

```
const path = (process.pkg) ? process.cwd() : __dirname;
```